# Custom style in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I use the following lines to change the style of the markdown cells

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
with open( './custom.css', 'r' ) as f: style = f.read()
HTML( style )
```

The file `custom.css` contains the lines

```
<style>
   div.text_cell_render {font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
</style>
```

This works as expected in `jupyter-notebook` (it changes the default font of the markdown) but it has no effect in `jupyter-lab`.

How am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JupyterLab uses different set of CSS classes than jupyter-notebook does.

To target markdown cells you want to use `jp-MarkdownOutput` class, e.g.:

```
<style>
   div.jp-MarkdownOutput {font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
</style>
```

You can read more on CSS in JupyterLab in [the documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/css.html).